Looping ssh command with `while` stopped at first iteration but not `for`
The following didn't work:
cat /etc/hosts | grep -vE '(^(#|$)|127.0.0.1|ff|::|node)' | awk '{print $1}' | while read -r host; do
    echo "Looking at $host"
    ssh "$host" commands
done

It just quit on the first iteration. I suspected the ssh somehow breaks the loop, so I tried to prepend it with echo:
cat /etc/hosts | grep -vE '(^(#|$)|127.0.0.1|ff|::|node)' | awk '{print $1}' | while read -r host; do
    echo "Looking at $host"
    echo ssh "$host" commands
done

It succeeded.
In the end I used for loop:
for host in $(cat /etc/hosts | grep -vE '(^(#|$)|127.0.0.1|ff|::|node)' | awk '{print $1}'); do
    echo "Looking at $host"
    ssh "$host" commands
done

It worked fine.
Why did the while fails?

GNU bash, version 5.0.3(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)


ssh consumes the standard input stream. See the duplicates for solutions.

@Kusalananda, interesting. I tried using ssh $host cat it printed everything. Is it intentional?
